# Why Valgrind cleans my input text file?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I got a code that I want to test where do I get a segfault. But when I run valgrind if keeps me turning to a place where I did nothing wrong. It ignores the input txt file and erases it.
here's the code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
FILE * input=fopen(argv[1],"r");
FILE * output=fopen(argv[2],"w");
int i,j,NumCrom;
int instancias=0,torres,InstanciaAtual=0;
    fscanf(input,"%i",&instancias);
//......
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

valgrind error:

```
 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==13878== Invalid read of size 4
==13878==    at 0x53A935A: __isoc99_fscanf (isoc99_fscanf.c:31)
==13878==    by 0x400CF0: main (main.c:18)
==13878==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

But nothing wrong with that part. It worked to read the txt separately by a function. It cleans the input txt everytime I start the valgrind and that's what returning this segfault (but it got other that doesn't return because the valgrind closes with the first segfault call before that).
Can anyone help me with that, please?
And thanks for any help on that.

Comment: Are you sure that your program is reading the text file successfully when you run it without Valgrind?

Comment: Are you sure `fopen(argv[1],"r");` is not returning `NULL`, that would be consistent with the error of an invalid read from `0x0`. It would helpful to know how you are running your program as well.

Comment: You don't check that you were passed two arguments.  You don't check whether you were able to open either file.  You use the unchecked value in `input` and get an error about reading a NULL pointer.  That's a fairly clear case of 'did not open file in `argv[1]` successfully' and is a reminder of why you must check before you use command line arguments and after calling functions like `fopen()`.

Comment: The program is reading the text successfully without the valgrind. The strange thing is that it cleans the input.txt everytime I use valgrind. But when I only run the exe, it returns a segfault and the input.txt isn't empty.

Comment: @BrenoSantos You need to add `NULL` check after the `fopen` if that is returning `NULL` then that is the source of the error and you need to determine why the file open is failing.

Answer (score 0):

fopen(argv[1],"r");

Is apparently returning NULL (which makes sense as it's Address 0x0), please make sure the file (specified in argv[1]) exists and(!) you do a NULL check in your code.

The segfault in fscanf is just naturally, since you try to read from NULL.
When you run with valgrind, did you maybe forget to pass the parameters?

Comment: I've pass the parameters to the valgrind.
valgrind ./exe input.txt output.txt
if argc<3, then I return EXIT_FAILURE.
the txt file start with the number of instances (and there's where the segfault starts). After I run valgrind the input.txt becames empty (but wasn't before).
And I can read the txt without the rest of the functions. I think there's another segfault. When I run normally only to read the input.txt it's working. But when I use valgrind only to read too, it returns segfault (that wasn't returning before only on execution).

Comment: Please add NULL checks after the fopen() calls... Also can you try addressing the input file with the full path? Usually it shouldn't matter, but if the working directory changes it might explain why the file isn't found. Is the file output.txt being generated ok?